# Manipulate the results stored within a 'promise'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I have a `service` that I wish to use to first grab an object from a JSON file and then to return selected data from said object, depending on what the user requests.

This service may be used multiple times per visit, so I don't wan the user to have to wait while the data is retrieved on every occasion.

I have set up the service to only request the JSON file once per page load, but I'm having some trouble extracting only the data that I wish to return.

My idea was to take a clone of the initial `promise` object (referred to as `promiseAll` in my code) and then manipulate the data within, before returning that cloned object (referred to as 'promiseSelected') to the user.

What I have below almost works, but if the users requests a list of type `searchable`, every future request has only the results for that request.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (or if there is a better way to do this), but I'd apprciate any pointers.

Here is how I am using the `service` -

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage', '$stationsList', function($scope, $localStorage, $stationsList){

    $stationsList.getList('searchable').then(function(data){
        $scope.stationsList = data; // Grab a list of searchable stations
    });

}]);
```

And here is the full `service` -

```
app.service('$stationsList', ['$http', function($http, $scope){

    var tempStations,
        promiseAll,
        promiseSelected;

    /**
     * Grab a list of the required stations
     *
     * @param string type               The type of list to return
     * @return object promiseSelected   A promise object containing the stations requested by the user
     */
    var getStationsList = function(type){

        if(!promiseAll){

            promiseAll = $http.get('stations.json').then(function(res){
                return res.data;    // Grab the JSON list of all stations
            });

        }

        promiseSelected = angular.copy(promiseAll); // Take a fresh copy of 'promiseAll'
        tempStations = [];                          // Reset to an empty array

        switch(type){

            case "searchable":

                promiseSelected = promiseAll.then(function(data){

                    [].map.call(data || [], function(elm){  // Map all stations...
                        if (elm.link.indexOf(".xml") > -1)  // Check to see if the station is searchable
                            tempStations.push(elm);         // It is - add the station to 'tempStations'
                    });

                    return tempStations;

                });

                break;

            case "locatable":

                promiseSelected = promiseAll.then(function(data){

                    [].map.call(data || [], function(elm){  // Map all stations...

                        if(
                        isFinite(parseFloat(elm.latitude)) &&
                        isFinite(parseFloat(elm.longitude))
                        )                                   // Check to see if the station is locatable
                            tempStations.push(elm);         // It is - add the station to 'tempStations'

                    });

                    return tempStations;

                });

                break;

            default:
                promiseSelected = promiseAll;

        }

        return promiseSelected;

    };

    return{
        getList: getStationsList
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Your clone is useless, and isn't used by your code anyway. I have a hard time understanding what you expect to happen and what happens instead. The problem is probably that you reuse the same tempStations variable evrywhere. This variable should be local to every function passed to then().

Comment: That simple little change appears to have done the job.  Please mark it up as the answer and I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you reuse the same `tempStations` variable everywhere. This variable should be local to every function passed to `then()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try to remember that in the future.